# Axis background shading overriding legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

This code in MATLAB:

```
hold on 
h(1) = area([0 2.5], [125 125]);
h(2) = area([2.5 5], [125 125]);
set(h(1),'FaceColor',[1.0 0.8 0.6],'EdgeColor',[1.0 0.8 0.6]);
set(h(2),'FaceColor',[1.0 0.8 0.4],'EdgeColor',[1.0 0.8 0.4]);
x = [0:1:5];
y1 = x.^2;
y2 = x.^3;
hLine1 = plot(x,y1,'r-o');
hLine2 = plot(x,y2,'g-s');
set(gca,'ylim',[0 125]); %left yaxis range
hleg1 = legend([hLine1 hLine2],{'line1','line2'});
```

Creates this plot:

[image: MATLAB generated plot]

And I export it to tikz using `matlab2tikz` and compile it in this .tex file (**Note: You need to comment out stack plots=y, or pgfplots gives an error, not sure why**):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1.00000,0.80000,0.40000}%

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.565625in,
area style,
%stack plots=y,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
ymin=0,
ymax=125,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot[fill=white!60!orange,draw=white!60!orange] plot table[row sep=crcr]{0  125\\
2.5 125\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=mycolor1,draw=mycolor1] plot table[row sep=crcr]{2.5  125\\
5   125\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot [color=red,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
1   1\\
2   4\\
3   9\\
4   16\\
5   25\\
};
\addlegendentry{line1};

\addplot [color=green,solid,mark=square,mark options={solid}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
1   1\\
2   8\\
3   27\\
4   64\\
5   125\\
};
\addlegendentry{line2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which results in this graph:

[image: latex render of same plot]

Questions:

1. As you can see the two background shadings have become the legend entrys... why?
2. Is there a better or proper way to shade the background of a plot?
3. How can I make pgfplots keep the black border around the whole plot? (not just the x and y axis)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers:

1. You need to pass the `forget plot` option to `\addplot` to exclude the background plots from the legend; I also commented out the option `area style` and shifted the legend a little (to prevent it from overlapping the plots) using `at={(0.9,0.95)` in the `legend style` key.
2. There might be another options using some coordinate systems, `axis cs`, or `axis description cs`, but your options is good.
3. Add the options `axis on top` to the axis environment; I also commented out the options `axis x line*=bottom` and `axis y line*=left`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1.00000,0.80000,0.40000}%

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.565625in,
%area style,
axis on top,
%stack plots=y,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
ymin=0,
ymax=125,
%axis x line*=bottom,
%axis y line*=left,
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left,at={(0.9,0.95)}}
]
\addplot[fill=white!60!orange,draw=white!60!orange,forget plot] plot table[row sep=crcr]{0  125\\
2.5 125\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=mycolor1,draw=mycolor1,forget plot] plot table[row sep=crcr]{2.5  125\\
5   125\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot [color=red,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
1   1\\
2   4\\
3   9\\
4   16\\
5   25\\
};
\addlegendentry{line1};

\addplot [color=green,solid,mark=square,mark options={solid}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
1   1\\
2   8\\
3   27\\
4   64\\
5   125\\
};
\addlegendentry{line2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SteveHatcher You're welcome. I just updated my answer with a shift to the legend that might be of interest for you.